# show multiple screens using visual web part sp 2010

Tags: web-part

i have few screens like data entry screen, data listing screens, data analysis screen,  voting screen in short i have 5-7 screens.

i m just wondering, what is best way to show them in single visual web part.

i dont want to have usercontrol for each screen as i m afraid, if i 'll load usercontrol dynamically, it will cause complexities for handling events and view states.. so any other solution with reference/sample/example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try Asp:MultiView Control in the Webpart and add the screens Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx)

Comment: i m afraid it will make web part very heavy that i put all controls on design time.